# Get text of td following the second occurrence of an element in Selenium using Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to find the text after a remarks field in a form.  However, the table has multiple remarks fields.  I want to be able to grab the text in the td that follows the td of the second remarks field.  I have the following html:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>...</tr> 
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Remarks:</td>
      <td>this is the first remarks field
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>AnotherField:</td>
      <td>Content of that field</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Remarks:</td>
      <td>this is the second remarks field</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>...</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

To grab the text out of the first remarks field, I can do the following:

```
ret = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[contains(text(),'Remarks')]/following::td")
print ret.text
```

However, I need to grab the content out of the second remarks field.  This has to be done based on the index of the occurrences of 'Remarks', not based on the  index.  I've wanted to try things like this:

```
ret = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[contains(text(),'Remarks')][1]/following::td")
```

or:

```
rets = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[contains(text(),'Remarks')]")[1]
ret = elements.find_element_by_xpath("/following::td")
```

Understandingly, these do not work.  Is there a way of doing this?  Using a command along the lines of 'the field after the nth occurrence of Remarks' is what I'm looking for.

P.S.  This will have to be done using xpath.  Reason being, I'm trying to convert a coworkers code into selenium from another application that has everything revolved around xpath.

I'm using Selenium-2.44.0 and Python 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexing starts from 1 in XPath:

```
(//td[contains(., 'Remarks')]/following-sibling::td)[2]
```

Or, you can use `find_elements_by_xpath()` and get the second item:

```
elements = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[contains(., 'Remarks')]/following-sibling::td")
print elements[1].text
```

Comment: nice answer, this was really helpful